# How to make Openstreet Map transparent now;

Tags: openstreetmap, overlay, transparency-opacity

I have a detailed DTM of my region and i want to overlay Openstreet Map with transparency. Is this possible and how; I work with Openlayer3

Comment: Can you give a bit more details about how you want to achieve this? I would know how to do this in qgis for example..

Comment: Which GIS software is your DTM using? QGIS can have OSM base maps with transparency settings.

Comment: I am using QGIS. In QGiS I just dircovert how to do it with QuickMapService plugin, but i want to make a web map so i need the html and javasrcipt code to do this if it possible

Answer (score 1):

The tiles supplied by openstreetmap.org are not transparent. You would need to either pay a third-party service provider (such as [thunderforest.com](http://thunderforest.com) or [geofabrik.de](http://geofabrik.de)) to create transparent tiles based on OSM data, or serve your own by using the tutorial at [switch2osm.org](http://switch2osm.org) and adapting the stylesheet.